# SSRS Get table last value from previous page

Tags: reporting-services

In Reporting Services imagine that i have a table with 1 column, that when is printed (2 pages) looks like this:

**1st Page**

Value

1

2

3

**2nd Page**

Value

4

5

6

What I need is that when it is printed looks like this:

**1st Page**

Value

1

2

3

**2nd Page**

Value

Last Value From Page 1: 3

4

5

6

Briefly what i want is that,in each page of the report (except in page 1) the first value is the last value from previous page...

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

There is built-in functionality to [display row and column headers on multiple pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207045.aspx).  This also tells you how to keep a static row or column visible while scrolling.  Note the KeepWithGroup and RepeatOnNewPage properties.

If the rows you would like to repeat across pages are not group headers, you may have to make your own page group.  This approach is not very pretty, but you could structure the data with flags to signal its own page breaks, and then manually include a repeat row after the page break.  So the data set would look like:

```
Value PageFlag
 1     1
 2     1
 3     1
 3     2
 4     2
 5     2
 6     2
```

You would add a grouping on `PageFlag` with a [page break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207058.aspx) for each group.

> On the **Page Breaks** tab, select **Between each instance of a
>   group** to add a page break between each instance of a group in the
>   table.

There is more detail on the KeepTogether property [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255248.aspx).  You can also read up on [Pagination](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255278.aspx) and [Page Layout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210530.aspx).